# update database that connection in flask app

Tags: python, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app that connects to the database table as shown below

```
connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=x;DATABASE=y; MARS_Connection=yes')
cursor = connection.cursor()

SQL = "select * from data"
table = pd.read_sql(SQL , con=connection)

print(table)
```

result

> ```
> id   name
> 1     v
> 2     u
> 3     o
> ```

if I update the database manually by adding

> ```
> 4     j
> ```

then I print it will not show in my flask app so I have to restart the app to show it.

my question how can I make sure that flask app will update variable based database updated

do I have to read the database again in each route, and save it in the same variable?
like

```
table = pd.read_sql(SQL , con=connection)
```

or there is another way?

Comment: yes. you need to re-fetch the data to get the updated data. there is plenty way to implement this, e.g. add some button on your APP that will manual refresh the data whenever you touch it.

Comment: that is good, but what if need it to be in the backend, is the only way that I have to read the table again?

Comment: I use a timer which auto refresh every few sec. not fancy and I am sure there will be a better implement but at least it work for me. and AFAIK I don't know any way to have a sync table that will present realtime data in database.